# Recursive query with conditions

Tags: sql-server

I have the following sample data:

```
==================================
id   name     parent   isactive
=================================
001  alfa     null       1
002  beta     001        0
003  carlie   001        1
004  daniel   002        1
005  echo     001        1
```

From this sample data, I want to output the following data:

```
=====
name
=====
alfa
carlie
echo
```

The following conditions should apply:

- `parent = null AND isactive = 1`
- `parent != null AND isactive = 1 AND parent_record.isactive = 1`

So both the parent and child records should have `isactive = 1` where there is a lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select *, 0 as level from tbl
 where parent is null and isactive = 1
 union all
 select t.*, level + 1
 from cte c
 inner join tbl t on c.id = t.parent and t.isactive = 1)

 select id, name, parent, isactive 
 from cte
```

A recursive CTE is used to solve this problem. At the top level, we select records which have no parents and which are active. For all other levels, we check that they have a parent and that they are active.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/SDNY48496)